# Git - Set master branch equal to DEV branch

Tags: git

I have a project in vscode and all the commit & push commands have been done in the DEV brunch.

Now, I want to put the master branch equal to the DEV branch (not merge).

How should I do that?

Answer (score 0):

If you want to rewrite the local branch master to what DEV is (locally):

```
git branch -f master DEV
```

If you mean on a remote:

```
git push --force some-remote DEV:master
```

Assuming you have a local branch called DEV.